# Two same type of C codes giving different output . Need help understanding this

Tags: c, scanf

```
int n;

scanf("%d",&n); //input from keyboard=5
printf("%d ",n); //gives output 5.

n=scanf("%d",&n); //input from keyboard=5
printf("%d ",n); //gives output 1.
```

Need help understanding the second one.

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled, which in this case is 1. See more: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: See [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

scanf returns the number of fields it assigns. So, first, it assigns n as 5. Then it returns 1 as it has assigned to only 1 variable. Then, n takes that value.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to use `scanf()`. In `C` standards `scanf()` always returns the number of conversion it did from `stdin`, in your case only 1 conversion is done, hence `1` is assigned to n.

In `C`, if you want to modify a parameter's value inside a function, you need to pass the address of the variable (`&var`) to that function, and the parameter of the function should be a pointer (`type *`). Then, you need to de-reference the pointer like (`*ptr`).

Now, we need to change the value of `n` inside `scanf()` function, that's why we need to give the address of `n`.

Comment: it's not pass-by-reference because there's no reference in C. C only has pass-by-value and this is passing the pointer value to the function

Comment: @phuclv From a caller point-of-view, arrays are passed by reference.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX since when is IBM docs the authoritarian document? Did you read the C standard? [Does C even have "pass by reference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17168623/995714). Passing the pointer then dereference it manually is no way "pass by reference" where everything is dereferenced automatically